# i got an error in login code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I tried writing a login code in vc#.. I got the following error..

> The type or namespace name 'LoginControl' does not exist in the namespace 'ErikSchmidt' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Please help me rectify this error.

Answer (score 1):

This means that Login Control is not visible to your code. What you need is specify LoginControl's namespace with using keyword or add assembly reference (with login control) to your project.

Answer (score 0):

.NET projects must define which assemblies they require (such as `System` in most C# programs). It looks like you didn't add a reference to the assembly that contains `LoginControl`. Right-click on "References" in the project (in "Solution Explorer") and add a reference to the required assembly (which is wherever `LoginControl` is contained in).